# Is this CSRF Countermeasure Effective?

Tags: security, web-applications, csrf

Please let me know if the following approach to protecting against CSRF is effective.

1. Generate token and save on server
2. Send token to client via cookie
3. Javascript on client reads cookie and adds token to form before POSTing
4. Server compares token in form to saved token.

Can anyone see any vulnerabilities with sending the token via a cookie and reading it with JavaScript instead of putting it in the HTML?

Answer (score 2):

The synchroniser token pattern relies on comparing random data known on the client with that posted in the form. Whilst you'd normally get the latter from a hidden form populated with the token at page render time, I can't see any obvious attack vectors by using JavaScript to populate it. The attacking site would need to be able to read the cookie to reconstruct the post request which it obviously can't do due to cross-domain cookie limitations.

You might find [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 5: Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-5.html) useful (lot's of general CSRF info), particularly the section on cross-origin resource sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If a persons traffic is being monitored the hacker will likely get the token also. But it sounds like a great plan. I would try to add a honeypot. Try to disguise the token as something else so It's not obvious. If it's triggered, send the bad user into the honeypot so they don't know they've been had.

My philosophy with security is simple and best illustrated with a story.
Two men are walking through the woods. They see a bear, freak out and start running. As the bear catches up to them and gaining one of them tells the other, "we'll never outrun this bear". the other guy responses, "I don't have to outrun the bear, I only have to outrun you!"

Anything you can add to your site to make it more secure the better off you'll be. Use a framework, validate all inputs (including all those in any public method) and you should be ok.

If your storing sensitive data I would setup a second sql server with no internet access. Have your back-end server constantly access your front-end server, pull and replace the sensitive data with bogus data. If your front-end server needs that sensitive data, which is likely, use a special method that uses a different database user (that has access) to pull it from the back-end server. Someone would have to completely own your machine to figure this out... and it would still take enough time that you should be able to pull the plug. Most likely, they'll pull all your data before realizing it's bogus... ha ha.

I wish I had a good solution on how to protect your customers better to avoid CSRF. But what you have looks like a pretty good deterrent.

Comment: This all seems a massive amount of work to create some obfuscation and avoid actually addressing the problem. I have a story as well: If you're not going to fix a problem, at least don't work hard at it. Your thoughts here on outrunning the bear assumes that the bear doesn't care whom he catches. If you're a bank, and the other guy is a news site, I'm thinking the attacker might continue chasing you even if you're a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/162/485) over on [Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com) has some useful discussion on the subject.

I especially like @AviD's answer:

```
Don't.
-
Most common frameworks have this protection already built in (ASP.NET, Struts, Ruby I think), or there are existing libraries that have already been vetted. (e.g. OWASP's CSRFGuard).
```